# Disabling or listening to system buttons (Back, Home, Overview) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, button

I'm developing a Flutter app and need to handle system buttons like Back, Home, and Overview. How can I override their default behavior or receive notifications when pressed?

I've researched but couldn't find a built-in solution within Flutter's sandbox. WillPopScope works for the Back button, but I'm unsure about handling Home and Overview buttons. Are there recommended approaches or available plugins/packages? Any guidance or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!